# I'm not been able to add session to my code, I'm trying to show the fractal only when is in London or New York session

Tags: pine-script

**That's a code that I'm trying to add**

```
london_sess = input.session("0700-1600", "London")
newyork_sess = input.session("1300-2200", "New York")

is_in_london = time(timeframe.period, london_sess)
is_in_newyork = time(timeframe.period, newyork_sess)
is_in_both = is_in_london and is_in_newyork
```

**How to add the code above to my code?**

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay=true)

bool confirmed_fractal      = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Plot only confirmed Fractals', tooltip = 'Switch "OFF" during backtest')
bool IB                     = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Plot Inside Bar')

isBWFractal(mode) =>
    ret = mode == 1 ? high[4] < high[2] and high[3] <= high[2] and high[2] >= high[1] and high[2] > high[0] : 
          mode == -1 ? low[4] > low[2] and low[3] >= low[2] and low[2] <= low[1] and low[2] < low[0] : false
    ret
//  ||-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------||

filteredtopf = isBWFractal(1)
filteredbotf = isBWFractal(-1)

if confirmed_fractal  == true
    filteredtopf := barstate.isconfirmed and isBWFractal(1)
    filteredbotf := barstate.isconfirmed and isBWFractal(-1)

plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
plotshape(filteredbotf, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
```

**I'm trying to add the condition, but It's not working with the plotshape**

```
if is_in_london or is_in_newyork 
plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
plotshape(filteredbotf, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
plotshape(is_in_both ? filteredtopf : na, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)

plotshape(is_in_both ? filteredbotf : na, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
```